# How can I add support for PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES algorithm in modern OpenJDK based JVM (Semeru)

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to run some legacy code using Semeru:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (build openj9-0.30.0, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20220128_306 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 9dccbe076
OMR      - dac962a28
JCL      - c1d9a7af7c based on jdk8u322-b06)
```

But this code depends on a proprietary Oracle cipher not included in OpenJDK anymore so when running:

```
Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES");
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:543)
```

I've tried including Bouncy Castle as an alternative provider, but without luck.

Any chance of getting some open source provider I can include that supports this?

I've tried specifying the provider as SunJCE, which should be included as per:

```
cat /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/java.security | grep security.provider
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
```

But got to the same error...

Comment: If the algorithm is not available in your environment, you can derive the key and IV explicitly. Here you can find the corresponding key derivation function [`PBECipherCore.deriveCipherKey()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBECipherCore.java#l261).

Comment: Thanks for the idea Topaco! The aim you suggest would be to create my own implementation of the PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES cipher?

Comment: Yes, which is relatively straightforward: `deriveCipherKey()` expects passphrase, salt and iteration count and needs to apply MD5 as digest. The first 24 bytes of the 32 bytes return value are the key, the last 8 bytes are the IV. With key and IV then the encryption/decryption can be done with TripleDES in CBC mode (`DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding`).

Comment: It's not OpenJDK; cryptoproviders have always been officially outside the 'Java spec' boundary and what used to be 'IBM Java' (mostly on AIX) had its own providers even though it passed TCK. But the Sun-then-Oracle providers _are_ still available in OpenJDK source (up to 17 at least), and the downloads I got from https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/downloads/ last month (8.0.312.7 11.0.13.8 17.0.1.12) DO have them -- including that Cipher. Can you try `getInstance` specifying SunJCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing my own solution just in case anyone else has the same issue.

That cipher is actually available in the /lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar file on the openjdk compilation (IBM Semeru Runtime Open Edition (build 1.8.0_322-b06)).

As posted on the question, it's actually on the provider list (index 6), but the jar was not being loaded. I have yet to investigate if there is any change on the extension classloader that I'm not aware of, but, so far, manually adding that jar to the application classpath has worked flawlessly and got the cipher working.